# Request DDE data using Python

Tags: python, pywin32, dde

I'm trying to request DDE data without success. Where's my code:

```
# DDE code
# LibreOffice equivalent of this code is: =DDE("profitchart"; "cot"; "DI1F23.ABE"; 1)

import win32ui
import dde


server = dde.CreateServer()
server.Create("profitchart")
conversation = dde.CreateConversation(server)
conversation.ConnectTo("profitchart", "cot")

requested_data = conversation.Request("DI1F23.ABE")

print(requested_data)




dde.error: Request failed
```

It's a dumb question, but I can't figure out...

I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: Where is `"profitchart"` supposed to be coming from, what DDE server provides that?

Comment: Profitchart is like an metatrader... And generates this code for Excel or Libreoffice...

Comment: It's impossible to say why your DDE server is not able to handle the request - your code appears fine, as `dde` is pretty straightforward. You'd need to look at the logs of Profitchart and work from there. Is the LibreOffice code you reference working without issue on the same machine?